# Why Is Not My Python 2.7 Script Working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I have this script using treq in Python 2.7, but it does not make the requests:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import time,hashlib,urllib2,json,treq

PasswordStart = 0
executed = []

def done(response):
    if response.code == 200:
        sys.stdout.write( Password )
    reactor.stop()
while PasswordStart<10001:    
    if PasswordStart not in executed and PasswordStart<10001:
        executed.append(PasswordStart)
        UserAgent = "Samsung Galaxy S8 - 7.0.0"
        Username = "JamesRicky"
        RegD = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        Password = str(PasswordStart).zfill(4)
        HASH = hashlib.md5()
        HASH.update(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+Password)
        url = "http://example.com/info"
        data = {'Password': Password, 'RegDate': RegD, 'UserName': Username}
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Reg-Date': RegD, 'User-Agent': UserAgent, 'Secret-Key': HASH.hexdigest()}
        d = treq.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        d.addCallback(done)
        PasswordStart+=1

reactor.run()
```

Why doesn't it work?

What my code is supposed to do, is to run this Post Request and each request should have a 4 digit Password (0000...9999). Every time the loop runs:

> if PasswordStart not in executed and PasswordStart<10001:

It is supposed to add the loop number (PasswordStart) in the executed array, so it does not rerun the same number twice. Then it will make the variables and then make the connection. It saves the response and the response gets checked at the end. If response.code == 200, then it will print out the password. Else, it will keep going through the loop and adding i+1 and PasswordStart+1.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you done anything to narrow down where and what the problem is?

Comment: Did you take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - It says _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_

Comment: Use the print statement.

Comment: I do not get any error messages, but I have clearly explain what it is supposed to do. The program runs, but does not make any connections to the requested URL.

Comment: @Elan I tried Print PasswordStart at the bottom of my loop, and it gives me the following output:
1

Which means it does not go through the loop.

Comment: I meant use the print statement to debug. SO doesn't debug for you. Nobody will.

Comment: What's the point of `i=i+1` at the bottom of the loop? The `for` statement will set `i` to the next element of `range(10000)` when the loop repeats, so the assignment is ignored.

Comment: I don't see that `if` statement anywhere in the loop. Why is it necessary, since `for i in range(10000):` will not repeat any value?

Comment: @Barmar, forgot to edit the code. The current code is what I have.

Comment: The code never uses `i` for anything, why do you need to make sure you don't reuse the same value? And since you're just incrementing it, how would you get a repeat in the first place?

Comment: `i` and `PasswordStart` always have the same values, why do you need two different variables? `PasswordStart` is the one you actually use.

Comment: @Barmar, I fixed the code. Now it runs through the loop, but still does not make any connections

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are stopping reactor in `done` function. Due to which your reactor will stop as soon as first response is received. Stopping a reactor will stop your script, even if there are pending callbacks. You need to improvise your logic to see if all the request are done then stop reactor.

treq is based on twisted. Check out this [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation) for more knowledge on event loop / reactor

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to batch up 10000 requests and then fire them all off simultaneously - and that's what your code is doing.

Check this old blog post, http://as.ynchrono.us/2006/05/limiting-parallelism_22.html